# Is Eclipse P2 provisioning fundamentally broken?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, provisioning

I have noticed that the Eclipse Equinox/P2 provisioning has some problems: if the download and/or update phase is interrupted, it can leave your Eclipse installation in an inconsistent state.

- What is the worse that can happen if P2 is interrupted during an update?
- Can P2 be used to upgrade to a new version of Eclipse (or a new version of a given RCP)?
- Are there alternatives or ways to make P2 more robust?

Answer (score 1):

If the download (collect) is interrupted, that won't leave your eclipse in an inconsistent state, and neither should the trust verification phase.  But if eclipse was killed during the installation phase or the configure phase, that might leave eclipse in an inconsistent state.

p2 supports updating Eclipse to new versions (3.5 to 3.6, and I've tried 3.6 to 3.7) although depending on the product version numbers it might be seen as a Uninstall 3.6/Install 3.7.  That will apply to RCP apps that are set up that way.  Just as in pre-p2, care has to be taken when creating features, including feature in other features, and determining what feature versions are update-compatible.